# Why is a Lambda function working with a layer when the dependencies are not even installed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I recently had a failed build due to the Lambda deployment package size [limitation of 250 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). This is after uncommenting `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/python"` in the deployment of the associated Lambda layer.

- I proceeded to comment it again (as a test), which means the layer dependencies, in this case `sqlalchemy`, is not installed in the layer.
- I tested the Lambda function making use of this layer and to my surprise, **it worked**! It definitely requires `sqlalchemy` to upload data to a DB as it makes use of the import `from sqlalchemy.orm import Session`
- The `sqlalchemy` library is not supported by AWS Lambda as seen [here](https://insidelambda.com/).
- Neither the Lambda function, nor the Lambda layer version referenced by the Lambda function has `sqlalchemy` installed.

Why is this working?

I downloaded the two different layer versions (with and without pip install) to check what was installed during creation in CloudFormation. I confirmed that the version referenced by the Lambda function does **not** contain `sqlalchemy`.

Note:

- Using Python 3.8 as a runtime in both the Lambda functions and layers.
- Not making use of Lambda function versioning, only layer versioning.

Comment: "Why is this working?" - because you are making mistake somewhere. Maybe using wrong layer, wrong function, layer version or function version? You have to double check what exactly you are calling and how.

Comment: I double-checked this a couple of times. I added more information on how I tried to debug it. I can post screenshots to make it clearer if required. The only thing I suspect now is that Lambda somehow caches libraries it has used before.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda function uses **another layer that already had the dependencies** (ie. `sqlalchemy`) installed, albeit *incorrectly* installed in those layers.

If you happen to experience a similar issue, make sure you check all layers that the Lambda function uses.

To confirm whether the library is available at runtime of the Lambda function, temporarily insert the below into your lambda handler code to inspect:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

directory_path = "/opt/python/"
contents = listdir(directory_path)
print(contents)
```